# unable to send kik message on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, kik

I am un able to send a simple text message on kik, my message contains a plain URL,
here is my sample code

```
KikMessage *message = [KikMessage articleMessageWithTitle:@"some title" text:@"sometext" contentURL:[final_page objectForKey:@"gallery_url"] previewURL:nil];

[[KikClient sharedInstance] sendKikMessage:message];
```

and I am getting this warning in console

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is
>   not in the window hierarchy!